# Haskell output a list of ascii value

Tags: list, haskell

For example I have a haskell list `[72,73,74,75]`, how can i output this list as a string?, all elements in the list are ascii value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can combine `map`, that applies a function to each element of a list, and the `chr` function, that convert an `Int` value to its `Char` equivalent:

```
> map chr [72,73,74,75]
"HIJK"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can convert an `Int` code point to a `Char` using `chr :: Int -> Char`; a `String` is just a list of `Char`s. Note that this'll work for any Unicode code point, not just ASCII, which is something you should be doing anyway.

You can find functions like this using [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/); just type something like `Int -> Char`, and it'll give you functions that match that type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'chr' from the module Char to convert the integer values to characters:

```
import Char

intListToString l = [ chr x | x <- l ]

main = do
  putStrLn $ "the string: " ++ (intListToString [72,73,74,75])
```

Running the above with 'runghci' gives:

```
the string: HIJK
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this list as a straight string or a list with commas? Unless you want to convert ASCII char values to their character counterparts (which was already covered), you can do the following:

```
concatMap show [72,73,74,75]
```

will give you a "72737475" string and

```
init $ tail $ show [72,73,74,75]
```

will give you a "72,73,74,75" string